# HTML HEAD " Default title" is not updating in magento

Tags: header

please visit this link: http://schoolboards4.newtrendzonline.com/

on "browser tab" or in header text you can see text "Galarainbow- magento theme homapage"

but in SYSTEM > CONFIGURATION > DESIGN > HTML HEAD, I changed Default title to "Display products"

but it's not displaying.

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check HTML Head value on store view level.

Comment: please update the cache

Comment: thanks a lot for both. In this theme , it's set like this = > we can edit this text in admin panel -> CMS -> Pages -> select Gala Rainbow Magento Theme - Homepage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can edit this text in admin panel -> CMS -> Pages -> select Gala Rainbow Magento Theme - Homepage